# Jackrabbit and HTTP range requests for large media files

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I have switched from accessing my media files from a network share to a regular http server since VLC player can issue http range request and this way I can jump right into the middle of a movie.

Lately I want to organise these files a bit more and thought about putting them into Jackrabbit.

Upload even large files works just fine, but getting the is more of a problem as Jackrabbits http access to the media files seems not be handle http range requests, bummer.

How difficult would it be to implement this, provided of course that the files are stored in a file system?

Günther